# Urban Airship Push Notification Missing Deep Link

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have an application with the urban airship plugin all set up. If the app is running in the background and a push notification is sent to it Urban Airship has the correct Deep Link waiting to be parsed. However if I Receive a push notification whilst the app is actually closed the Depp Link string is empty.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post some code on how you are getting the deep link? Are you relying on the Urban Airship deep link action? The default behavior of the action is to only run when a notification is opened.

Comment: Hi there I am using the default Urban Airship Action. I then have a handler that checks if there is indeed a string for the deeplink using the GetDeepLink(Boolean) Method. It is always empty if the app was closed before and always full if not.

Comment: Could you post some code? I need some more context to help. The Urban Airship action tries to start an activity with the provided deep link, its up to the app to handle it. https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/blob/master/urbanairship-sdk/src/main/java/com/urbanairship/actions/OpenExternalUrlAction.java#L49

Comment: I managed to find my issue was rather silly in the end. The Uairship plugin has accessor functions to get the info on the last push. Unfortunately for me they have optional parameters that are always set to true to clear the data. I was aware of one of the functions having that but no the other.

Comment: Oh you are using either Unity, Cordova, or Titanium? That would be helpful info next time you post.